# Django REST Framework: Integrity error when creating tokens

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I would like to generate a token for every new user, using a custom user model called Account. However, the `authtoken_token` table seems to have a foreign key with the default user table called `auth_user`. This gives the following Integrity error:

> ```
>  django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child
>  row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_edibus`.`authtoken_token`,
>  CONSTRAINT `authtoken_token_user_id_56c22f4b_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN
>  KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
> ```

Here's how I generate new tokens inside my models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

As recommended by the REST Framework docs, I added the "needed_by" attribute to the initial migrations of my "authentication" app:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    needed_by = (
        ('authtoken', '0001_initial'),
    )

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Account',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', auto_created=True, serialize=False)),
                ('password', models.CharField(verbose_name='password', max_length=128)),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name='last login', blank=True)),
                ('username', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)),
                ('is_admin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'tbl_authentication_account',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

However, even this didn't help. After changing the foreign key manually in the database, the tokens were successfully generated, but authentication tests still fail.

Could someone please point out what I might be doing wrong with the migrations?

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py`? It looks like you might have run the migrations and created the rest framework token table before you did this. Therefore, the user foreign key is pointing to the built in user model. Are you sure you want to use a custom model? Your `Account` model looks very similar to the built in user. Using a custom model complicates things.

Comment: It looks like the relation from token goes to the users table... I concur to @Alasdair 's opinion: the AUTH_USER_MODEL isn't properly set up.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I actually declared `AUTH_USER_MODEL` at the bottom of my settings.py file. After Alasdair's recommendation, I decided to use the default User model, which indeed made things simpler.